# Inflated views lose their state when fragment is popped from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I inflate the same layout multiple times and add them to the same container view. Here is what I do:

### layout_inflated.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

</LinearLayout>
```

I inflate this layout and add to another view like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    final View rowLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_inflated, null, false);
    rowLayout.setTag(i);
    containerView.addView(rowLayout);
}
```

Then, suppose I enter the numbers `"111"`, `"222"` and `"333"` to the first, second and third rows' edittexts. Then I check the RadioButton on 3rd row, and leave 1st and 2nd rows' RadioButtons unchecked. Then I move to next fragment and this fragment is put into backstack. And then I move back to this fragment, and it is popped out of backstack. At this point, all 3 RadioButtons become checked, and all edittexts have `"333"` in their boxes. That is, all rows have the third row's state.

But, if I do not inflate rows from the same xml and create rows like the following, then everything works fine:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    rowLayout.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
    EditText edittext = new EditText(context);
    rowLayout.addView(radioButton);
    rowLayout.addView(editText);
    containerView.addView(rowLayout);
}
```

I suspect that when I inflate the same xml multiple times and add them to the same parent view, since all of them have same id's, something happens and Android cannot differentiate them. My real row layout is much more complex and cannot create it dynamically, I have to inflate it from xml. So, can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can avoid it?

**Edit:** When I debug, I see that `onTextChanged()` and `onCheckedChanged()` methods are called automatically when fragment is popped out of backstack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the same element's id in one view. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#IDs)

> View IDs need not be unique throughout the tree, but it is good practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of the tree you are searching.

And as I know `findViewById()` method will return the first occurrence of a View with the provided id. It can be reason why system redraw your views with values from only last view then the activity return from backstack.

So just remove android:id from xml file. If you need them use `setId(int id)`.